# OpenIDConnect Response Type Confusion

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I've spend the last few days reading through all the specs with regards to OAuth2 and OpenIDConnect and implementing a test client using Thinktecture Identity Server.  I've also followed several pluralsight courses and I think understand the main gist of it. However i'm still extremely confused about the Response Types.

OpenIDConnect spec specifies that the Hybrid flow response types are a combination of "code", "id_token" and "token".  I understand the "id_token" allows us to get access to basic id information initially.

I also understand code" refers to the authorization code and "token" refers to an access token and combining "code" with one or both of the other two triggers the flow but my understanding was that you swap an authorization code for an access token in the Authorization flow, while the Implicit flow supplies the Access Code implicitly?

Could someone clear up my confusion?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The following statements that you made are correct:

- `code` refers to the Authorization Code
- `token` refers to an Access Token or (`access_token`)
- in the Authorization Code flow one switches the `code` for an `access_token`

But part of your confusion may originate from terminology mixup:

- the term Authorization flow is not entirely correct; its official name is Authorization Code flow
- the term Access Code does not exist
- the Implicit flow does not have an Authorization Code (nor Access code) in fact there's no credential (or *grant*) involved at all that allows the Client to get tokens from the Token endpoint, hence it's name

As @juanifioren pointed out, Hybrid flows combine things:

- the `code id_token` flow would get a `code` and `id_token` in the Authentication Response directly but you'd use the `code` to get an `access_token` from the Token endpoint
- the `code token` flow would get a `code` and `access_token` in the Authentication Response directly but you'd use the `code` to get an `id_token` and possibly another `access_token` in the backend from the Token endpoint
- the `code id_token token` flow would get a `code`, `access_token` and an `id_token` in the Authentication Response directly **and** you could use the `code` in the backend to get **another** `access_token` from the Token endpoint

Getting an `access_token` from the Token endpoint differs from getting it from the Authorization endpoint because the confidential clients authenticate themselves to the Token endpoint (and not to the Authorization endpoint). Hence the `access_token` for the confidential part of the client might have more permissions and or a longer life.

See also a short thread on the spec mailing list on this topic: http://lists.openid.net/pipermail/openid-specs-ab/Week-of-Mon-20150209/005229.html

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the terminology - I'm still unsure why I would need a second `access_token` from the `token_endpoint`? Would it because I may have an app which can use both flows?

Comment: yes, if your app is capable of both flows it can get 2 access tokens; it may choose to do so because it trusts the backchannel flow more than the frontchannel

Comment: Another reason is that a refresh token is only issued on the backchannel. You'd never get a refresh token using implicit flow, so the same should hold true for a token returned from the authorization endpoint during hybrid flow.

Answer (score 20):

To understand the possible relationships between  Response Types and Grant Types see [IdentityServer4\Constants.cs](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Constants.cs#L33)

```
public static readonly Dictionary<string, string> ResponseTypeToGrantTypeMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { OidcConstants.ResponseTypes.Code, GrantType.AuthorizationCode },
            { OidcConstants.ResponseTypes.Token, GrantType.Implicit },
            { OidcConstants.ResponseTypes.IdToken, GrantType.Implicit },
            { OidcConstants.ResponseTypes.IdTokenToken, GrantType.Implicit },
            { OidcConstants.ResponseTypes.CodeIdToken, GrantType.Hybrid },
            { OidcConstants.ResponseTypes.CodeToken, GrantType.Hybrid },
            { OidcConstants.ResponseTypes.CodeIdTokenToken, GrantType.Hybrid }
        };
```

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Your thoughts about Authorization Code Flow and Implicit Flow are right.
But I think you are over-complicating the hybrid flow. When using hybrid you just simply can get both code and id_token.

After that, either you can grab code and exchange it for access token or just use the id_token (or access token) directly. Both approaches have their own flaws, especially in terms of security.

Comment: What you are saying is correct for "code id_token" response_type, but there is also "code token" and "code id_token token" strings defined. What are the real-world use cases when you'd want these values for response_type? The spec gives us no hint, and I frankly have no idea. In general, I think the advantage of hybrid flow is that the signed and encrypted id_token adds security to the communication of the unprotected front channel, especially if your client is using a key from a pre-registered jwks. (BTW, you can compare the tokens in the Gluu Server LDAP to see the differences.)

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@darutk/diagrams-of-all-the-openid-connect-flows-6968e3990660#9401

> **6. response_type=code token**
>
> When the value of response_type is code token, an authorization code
>   and an access token are issued from the authorization endpoint, and an
>   access token is issued from the token endpoint. In addition, if openid
>   is included in the scope request parameter, an ID token is issued from
>   the token endpoint, too.
>
> Both the authorization endpoint and the token endpoint issue an access
>   token, but the contents of the access tokens are not always the same.
>   Regarding this, “3.3.3.8. Access Token” in OpenID Connect Core 1.0
>   says as follows:
>
> If an Access Token is returned from both the Authorization Endpoint
>   and from the Token Endpoint, which is the case for the response_type
>   values code token and code id_token token, their values MAY be the
>   same or they MAY be different. Note that different Access Tokens might
>   be returned be due to the different security characteristics of the
>   two endpoints and the lifetimes and the access to resources granted by
>   them might also be different.