# Cannot log in or get access token with Google Authorization on Blazor WASM Standalone app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly

I'm having trouble logging in using Google OIDC as an identity provider with my Blazor WASM Standalone app. Here is my appsettings.json. I currently have the `ResponseType` set to `code`. This is what is causing it to break. If I set it to `id_token` I can log in, but then cannot get the access token in my component.

```
 "Local": {
    "Authority": "https://accounts.google.com/",
    "ClientId": "4....apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "https://localhost:44380/authentication/logout-callback",
    "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:44380/authentication/login-callback",
    "ResponseType": "code"
  }
```

My component:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
@page "/projects"
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider
@inject IAccessTokenProvider _tokenProvider
<h3>Projects</h3>

@code {

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authstate = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var accessTokenResult = await _tokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();
    }

}
```

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

        builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
        {
            // Configure your authentication provider options here.
            // For more information, see https://aka.ms/blazor-standalone-auth
            builder.Configuration.Bind("Local", options.ProviderOptions);
            
        });

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your the value you have set for the `ResponseType`. OIDC allows for hybrid flows and multiple types to be used. You need to add `token` to your response type if you want to be able to access the access token with the IAccessTokenProvider.

The following will work:

```
 "Local": {
    "Authority": "https://accounts.google.com/",
    "ClientId": "4....apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "https://localhost:44380/authentication/logout-callback",
    "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:44380/authentication/login-callback",
    "ResponseType": "id_token token"
  }
```

For more info on this check out this answer: [OpenIDConnect Response Type Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275477/openidconnect-response-type-confusion)